# Iterating through hashtable and using the get and containsKey methods

Tags: java, hashtable, chaining

Having trouble with the containsKey and get method, also not sure how to iterate through the hashtable keys and values, I want to iterate through and add the keys with the value of true to the solution list

1st error: The method containsKey(int) is undefined for the type hashTable

2nd error: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

3rd error: The method get(int) is undefined for the type hashTable

```
  package practice;

        import java.util.*;
        /*

        You are given an integer array, where all numbers except for TWO numbers appear even number of times. 

        Q: Find out the two numbers which appear odd number of times.

        */

        public class hashTable{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] test = {2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4};
            List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Hashtable<Integer, Boolean> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Boolean>(); 
            Boolean check = true;
            for (int item : test){
//error             if (!containsKey(item)){
                    check = true;
                } else{
                    check = false;
                    ht.put(item, check);

                }
                }

//error            for (int item : ht){
//error             if (get(item) == true){
                    solution.add(item);
                }
                }
            System.out.println("the result is");
            System.out.println(solution);
            }

         }
```

Comment: Change from `Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();` to `Hashtable<Integer, String> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();`

Comment: If your input array is always sorted, as in your code, you don't need a Hashtable. You can count the number of occurrences of each integer with a single iteration over the input array.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using hashtable? AFAIR, it is deprecated. Use HashMap instead.

Comment: No, it isn't deprecated. Universities haven't upgraded their curricula since Java 1.0 so that's what they still teach.

Comment: Okay the hashtable works now, how do I do chaining and how do I get the number of chains in a hashtable? I cant find it in the documentaion

Comment: I edited the post to show the new problem, Im not sure how to check if an element is in the hashtable or not and how to remove an element from the hashtable

Comment: Have edited the question, having trouble iterating through the hashtable and using the get and containsKey methods

Comment: Your *own* class's name is `hashTable` and I don't see any `containsKey()` method definition there. But, more generally, you are being dumbfounded by the very basic problems of elementary syntax. I suggest taking a deep breath, shaping up, and taking time to carefully analyze what you are actually doing there.

Comment: there is no containsKey method but there is a containsKey method in the hashtable class in java.utils which I import

Comment: You wrote `containsKey(item)` and also `get(item)`. On which object do you think you're invoking those methods?

Comment: How would I use the get and containsKey found in Hashtable? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

I tried used Hashtable.containsKey like in other languages but that also didn't work

Comment: And how would the `containsKey` method have any idea which hashtable you mean? Note that right now you are asking *the* most basic question about OO programming.

Comment: ...ht.containsKey(). Ahh! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue would seem that you are using a generic type without providing the generic information. If you put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` (or something along those lines, do not have an IDE to test), the warning should go away. That being said, I would advise against that.

Ideally, you should provide generic information and do as @BackSlash suggested: `Hashtable<Integer, String> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();`. This will provide the compiler with the generic information it needs and makes your collection **type safe** which is something you usually want.

That being said, I would recommend a different approach:

1. Iterate over your array.
2. Create a hash table: `HashTable<Integer, Boolean>`.
3. If the number you are iterating on exists in the hash table, then apply the not operator on the value at `HashTable[number]`.
4. If not, add a new entry and set the boolean value to false.

Seeing your comment, you could try something like so:

```
Hashtable<Integer, Boolean>  table = new Hashtable<Integer, Boolean>();
int[] nums = ...
for(Integer number : nums)
{
    if(table.containsKey(number))
    {
        table.put(number, !table.get(number));
    }
    else
    {
        table.put(number, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is if the number appears 3 times then it should be returned but in this scenario it wouldnt be

Comment: @FullCombatBeard: The first time that `x` appears, you would have `[x, false]`. The second time it would appear, you would have `[x, true]`. The third time it appears, you will get `[x, false]`. When you go through the hash table in the end, it will point out that `x` does not appear an even amount of time, which from what I am getting, is what you are after.

Comment: I have tried to implement what you are saying but I am running into some problems using the hashtable's methods

Comment: @FullCombatBeard: I have tried to add some code. See if it helps.